# Keep only recent history of the git repo (because of the broken commit)?

Tags: git

I have a problem with my git repository.

I wanted to push it to the github but it seems that I have missing commit (`21ad3b15ed4c0088cf5ca88b9f2a93a64c0dea2f`).

```
➜  md git:(master) ✗ git push -u origin master
error: Could not read 21ad3b15ed4c0088cf5ca88b9f2a93a64c0dea2f
fatal: revision walk setup failed
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:m4rx9/geekbookx.git'
```

I tried to recover this missing comment but I was not able to do it. Now I think I would like to push everything recent to this commit and ignore the old history. Or is there any other way to solve the problem to have on my github the recent history of the repo and ignore the very old history?

There is no remote repository yet. I wanted to push to code now but I'm not able because of the corruptions in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push --force` to overwrite any commits on the same branch that differ in your remote repository.

**This will distroy anything that exists in your remote but not in your local repository**, so use with caution.

Comment: There is no remote repository yet. I wanted to push to code now but I'm not able because of the corruptions in the repo.